# How to temporarily redirect front page of a network to one of the sites/blogs?

Tags: multisite, redirect

After setting up a multisite wordpress, I'd like to be able to redirect the root (front page) to one of the blogs.

To understand the context, I'm talking about an NGO that organises events, while active the homepage should redirect there.

The solution I found on a couple of forums involved manually changing the ID of the intended target site. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: This might help: [default Multisite redirect to one particular blog](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/default-multisite-redirect-to-one-particular-blog?replies=8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code goes in your child themes functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpsites_redirect_ms_front_page' );

function wpsites_redirect_ms_front_page() {
    if ( is_main_site() && is_front_page() ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/', 302 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Something like this should work (untested).

**Modify Code**

Simply swap out the URL in the code above.

You can also change the 302 to 301 or any other type of redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I reached at the moment is using a different theme for the main (root) instance and just adding a php header redirect in header.php

I still hope it's not the most elegant solution though :)

Comment: Please try my code as i haven't tested it on a Multisite installation. Thanks.